# PHP Function Help

Tags: php, twitter

Here is the function im trying to us, its held in a file called function.php

```
   public function updateProfile($name = null, $email = null, $url = null, $location = null, $description = null)
        {
            // validate parameters
            if($name === null && $email === null && $url === null && $location === null && $description === null) throw new TwitterException('Specify at least one parameter.');
            if($name !== null && strlen($name) > 40) throw new TwitterException('Maximum 40 characters allowed for name.');
            if($email !== null && strlen($email) > 40) throw new TwitterException('Maximum 40 characters allowed for email.');
            if($url !== null && strlen($url) > 100) throw new TwitterException('Maximum 100 characters allowed for url.');
            if($location !== null && strlen($location) > 30) throw new TwitterException('Maximum 30 characters allowed for location.');
            if($description !== null && strlen($description) > 160) throw new TwitterException('Maximum 160 characters allowed for description.');

            // build parameters
            if($name !== null) $aParameters['name'] = (string) $name;
            if($email !== null) $aParameters['email'] = (string) $email;
            if($url !== null) $aParameters['url'] = (string) $url;
            if($location !== null) $aParameters['location'] = (string) $location;
            if($description !== null) $aParameters['description'] = (string) $description;

            // make the call
            $response = $this->doCall('account/update_profile.xml', $aParameters, true);

            // convert into xml-object
            $xml = @simplexml_load_string($response);

            // validate
            if($xml == false) throw new TwitterException('invalid body');

            // return
            return (array) $this->userXMLToArray($xml, true);
        }
```

In index.php I have:

```
<php?

require_once("function.php");
$Twitter = new Twitter;

?>
```

I need to update the profile location?

Comment: You'd better use `<?php` instead of `<php?`

Comment: this is going to be really difficult if you don't know how to use classes and their methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you require the file, all you need to do is call the function:

```
<?php
require_once("function.php");
updateProfile("username", "email", "url", "location", "description");
?>
```

However, your function seems to be part of a class - but your example code doesn't show the class. If it is part of a class, I'll assume it's called 'Twitter'. In that case the code your using is close. It would be along the lines of:

```
<?php
require_once("function.php");
$Twitter = new Twitter;
$Twitter->updateProfile("username", "email", "url", "location", "description");
?>
```

Of course the class would have to do some kind of authentication, which the function your posted seems to refer to - `$this->doCall()`. Again the bulk of the class is missing, so this function by itself wouldn't do what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just asking how to call the function? I'm not familiar with the Twitter API, but I expect it'd be something like this:

```
$Twitter->updateProfile(null, null, null, 'new-location');
```

Each argument is optional and has a default value of `null`, so if you only want to pass in a particular argument, then just use `null` for all arguments before that one.